# Canonical question about parsing mathematical expressions for duplicate closure

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, canonical

Is there any canonical question about parsing mathematical expressions<sup>1</sup> with the proper tools and methods, which can be used for duplicate closure?

<sup><sup>1</sup> A somewhat OK answer should be able to parse an expression with the basic operators `+` (binary and unary), `-` (binary and unary), `*`, `/` and arbitrarily nesting `()`. A better answer would layout the idea and framework to add support for mathematical functions and other binary operators, plus handling associativity.</sup>

It would be great if there is a list of language-specific Q&A, plus a language agnostic Q&A.

Such questions show up frequently in the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), and they are answered in minutes with regex. Those are usually terrible solutions which breaks like twig on slightly more complex input.

Comment: Is it really that frequent? And for what kind of math expressions? Just nested number arithmetics, and/or functions etc.? And I believe it makes sense to finally differentiate between "parsing" and "matching". Only Perl can really utilize regexps for parsing.

Comment: @mario: It is less frequent that HTML/XML and JSON, but it accumulates over the time. I think a canonical question also benefits other languages which don't have built-in facility to parse expressions, where such kind of question may pop up from time to time. What use is there for a bunch of questions with bad solution? It is spreading the incorrect knowledge and bad implementation.

Comment: Canonical questions are great. And there's nothing wrong with making new/artifical ones. Just not sure if this topic can be covered language-agnostic though. It's potentially even a little broad, even if it's just an expression parser.

Comment: Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: @FlorentBayle: The accepted answer there is not a good answer in my opinion. The rest, well, probably needs a lot of polishing, imo.

Comment: Python: [canonical question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279) and ["somewhat OK answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That one is good. Would you please post that as an answer to this question?

Comment: @nhahtdh: a canonical answer would be the approach from [Unix programming environment book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoc_(programming_language)).

Comment: Java: in practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java

Comment: C language: questions about mathematical expression parsing show up periodically (I saw one today), but a good expression parser in C is too broad for SO, and a generic overview won't help the newbie's that are writing the questions. OTOH, if you want to write and post the canonical shunting-yard parser for C (with full error handling, operator precedence, and nested parentheses), go for it :-)

Comment: [Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/572796/960757) - [JclExprEval](http://stackoverflow.com/a/572863/960757) (currently accepted). Might be taken for C# as well.

Comment: At least one company in Cambridge(UK) used(maybe still does) this as a coding test that has to completed before shortlisting is done.